# Is operations $1 * x$ where $x \in R$ considered a "flop" i.e. a multiplication operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

As part of developing the working principles of an Implicit Double Step QR algorithm, a particular section asks us to count the flops for the following operation

$B - v * (u^T*B)$ where $u = [1,u_2,u_3]^T$ and $B \in R^{3 \times k}$ and $v = \gamma u$

Now for the $u^T*B$ part, if we just considered vector matrix multiplication, then there should be $3k$ multiplications and $2k$ additions. However, a number of my cohorts are saying the $1 * b_{nj}$ operations where $n = 1,2,3$ and $k = 1,2,3...k$ is not counted as a "flop". Hence the number of multiplications in the above step is $2k$ not $3k$.

Is this really the case i.e. why $1 * a_{ij}$ multiplications are not counted as a flop operation?

Comment: This question is off topic here, as it really pertains to how the calculation is implemented in the software, etc.

Comment: @K.Jiang No I believe my question is relevant. I was primarily asking whether when 1 is multiplied by an element, is it the convention to count it as 1 flop or not from a theoretical Linear Algebra perspective? I wasn't asking anything specifically about any software implementation

Comment: "is it the convention to count it as 1 flop or not from a theoretical Linear Algebra perspective" Linear algebra does not really *care* how many "flops" you assign a floating-point operation. These terms are not even defined in linear algebra. Your question (if I understand correctly) is about performance of a numerical calculation, which is probably not the best fit on this site in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flop count depends on the exact code you write. If you use a general matrix multiplication function then the computer will calculate $1 \cdot b_{nj}$ and so flops will be performed. If you write customized code for this algorithm then it's possible to skip those multiplications since you know there will always be $1$s there, so then those flops wouldn't take place.

For most algorithm analysis purposes, it doesn't matter that much; the point of counting flops is to get a rough estimate of your runtime cost and the $2k$ vs $3k$ may not be so important if this algorithm is one part of a larger implementation. However, sometimes a certain chunk of linear algebra really is the main runtime bottleneck, and in those cases it may be worth experimenting with optimizations like avoiding those multiplications by $1$.

Flop counting analysis can be very useful in guessing which parts of your algorithm are potential bottlenecks, but you should still confirm your optimization-related ideas by actual benchmarking; when you're talking about a smallish reduction in flops, there are several other factors that might make the final efficiency win tip one way or the other.